# Build Spanning Tree Graph

Tags: c++

I need to build a spanning tree of the graph and print count of edges a spanning tree and this edges. If we can't make a spanning tree, cin -1

For example

input

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

output

```
2
1 2
3 2
```

input

```
0 0
0 0
```

output

```
-1
```

I used dfs, but this work badly

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int>IntPair;

vector<vector<int>>g;
vector<bool>mark;
vector<IntPair>ostov;
int n;
int cc = 0;
ifstream fin("input.txt");
ofstream fout("output.txt");


void dfs(int v)
{
    if (mark[v])
        return;
    if (!mark[v])
    {
        mark[v] = true;         
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < g[v].size(); i++)
    {       
        int w = g[v][i];
        mark[g[i][v]] = true;
        if (w == 1 && v!=w)
        {
            cc++;
            ostov.push_back(make_pair(v + 1, w + 1));
        }
        dfs(w);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    bool check = false;
    fin >> n;
    g.resize(n);    
    mark.assign(n, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            fin >> a;           
            g[i].push_back(a);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {       
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            check = false;
            if (g[i][j] == 1)
            {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!check)
        {
            fout << "-1";
            return 0;
        }           
    }
    bool c1 = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        dfs(i); 

    fout << cc << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ostov.size(); i++)
    {
        if (c1)
        {
            fout << endl;
        }
        c1 = true;
        fout << ostov[i].first << " " << ostov[i].second;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can start with Prim's algorithm, it's pretty straightforward. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall its for minimum spanning tree

Comment: So you particulary need a non-minimum spanning tree? That is a little uncommon, but if you want to use BFS, you might want to check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601781/create-spanning-tree-with-dfs

Comment: If you want specific help with your code, please provide an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall edit